# Call variable from within a string

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Powershell to open AD U&C in another domain (/domain switch) using a variable.

No domain switch used, works (just not the domain I want):

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $domvar'\'$id -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process mmc -verb Runas -ArgumentList "C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc"}'
```

Defining a specific domain in an array works:

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $domvar'\'$id -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process mmc -verb Runas -ArgumentList @("C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc" /domain=domain.com)}'
```

BUT
Adding `/domain=$domain` does not (double quoting everything in the ArgumentList did not help):

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $domvar'\'$id -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process mmc -verb Runas -ArgumentList "C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc" /domain=$domain}'
```

NOR
Changing domain.com to my variable `$domain`:

```
Start-Process powershell -Credential $domvar'\'$id -ArgumentList '-command &{Start-Process mmc -verb Runas -ArgumentList @("C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc" /domain=$domain)}'
```

Also, a new window pops up and I see the red error font but I'm not sure how to grab that information. Tried using debugging and stepping into but didn't work.

Comment: `Start-Process "C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc" -Credential "${domvar}\${id}" -Verb runas`

Comment: "Start-Process : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters."

I've read elsewhere that Credential and Verb cannot be used together. I think that is the issue with that line.

Comment: Please run the statement exactly as I posted it (after defining `$domvar` and `$id` of course). Do not add anything. Do not leave anything out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In powershell single quotes do NOT perform variable substitution.  In your case you can probably just change the single quotes around your command to double quotes.  For the double quotes inside the quoted string you can include the `$` as a literal by preceding it with a backtick.

```
"-command &{Start-Process mmc -verb Runas -ArgumentList `"C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc`" /domain=$($domain)}"
```

Comment: Thank you! It was a matter of using the right quotes.  

This is what the final code looks like:

"-command &{Start-Process mmc -verb Runas -ArgumentList `C:\Windows\System32\dsa.msc /domain=$domain'}"

Comment: :) I get a message when voting that it doesn't publicly show until I've reached a reputation score of 15. I did now accept this as the answer. I'll be back to this thread in the near future. Again thank you!!

Comment: If you click the little star underneath your question voting stats, it will appear in your favorites.  of course since it's YOUR question it will also appear in your SO profile of questions asked.